# "No input file specified" nginx does not interpret php

Tags: php, nginx

I have replaced in PHP the configuration from apache to nginx, and this is what my nginx config looks like

```
user              nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type text/html;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    # The default server is in conf.d/default.conf
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}
```

Also, my server's configuration looks like this

```
 server {
     listen 80;
     server_name  prod.my-domain.com;
     root   /usr/share/nginx/html/prod.my-domain.com;

     location / {
           root /usr/share/nginx/html/prod.my-domain.com;
     }

   location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /root/share/nginx/html/prod.my-domain.com$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
   }
```

All the HTML files/images are shown, but php files, even if its `index.php` show

> No input file specified

I have error reporting on. I don't know what the problem is

### edit

Ok, I changed the server configuration to the below

```
 server {
     listen 80;
     server_name  demo.simons.co.de;
     root   /usr/share/nginx/html/prod.my-domain.com;

     location / {
           root /usr/share/nginx/html/prod.my-domain.com;
          index index.php index.html index.htm;
     }

   location ~.\.php$ {
      #  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
      # fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /root/share/nginx/htmli/$document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
   }
```

Now, when I visit this url `prod.my-domain.com/index.php` I see only black page
but `prod.my-domain.com/index.html` I can see all the contents

Comment: Is port 9000 on your server open and routing requests to fastcgi?

Comment: Maybe this can be useful: http://www.sitepoint.com/setting-up-php-behind-nginx-with-fastcgi/

Comment: I edited the file, even did as the link, but still no change

Comment: `location ~.\.php$ {` looks a little funny...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I removed the dot after `~` I had to put it, because I saw that in other tutorial. I have been searching all day to fix this problem

Comment: finally this made it. http://serverfault.com/questions/322018/nginx-not-executing-php-files

Answer (score 0):

`fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;`

Are you sure somebody listen there?

It isn't enough to configure nginx. 
Also you need fastcgi broker to manage fastcgi instances.
For example - php-fpm or spawn-fcgi from lighttpd package.

If it is - check that broker has file access permissions to /root/share/nginx/html....

Comment: I got my answer here http://serverfault.com/questions/322018/nginx-not-executing-php-files thanks for the effort